# Why does flutter streambuilder query using 'orderby' cause an error

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Why does my `StreamBuilder` return something went wrong? This stream works perfectly fine but when  add `orderBy` it says that something went wrong.
[Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNKyw.png)

```
Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 20,
                      ),
                      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection("notifications")
                            .where("parentUID",
                                isEqualTo:
                                    FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid)
                            .orderBy('timestamp')
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (BuildContext context,
                            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                          if (snapshot.hasError) {
                            return Text('Something went wrong');
                          }

                          if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                            return Text("Loading");
                          }
                          return Column(
                            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map(
                              (DocumentSnapshot document) {
                                Map<String, dynamic> data =
                                    document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                                return adminNotifCard(
                                  text1: data['notifTitle'],
                                  text2: data['notifNotes'],
                                );
                              },
                            ).toList(),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKqWU.png)

Comment: Going forward, if `snapshot.hasError` returns `true`, you'll want to log the actual error from `snapshot.error`. That will tell you precisely what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the issue by going to the index tab in cloud firestore
[image]

[image]

And chose the notification collection and made it ascending, it didnt work at first, but after saying `building`, it said enabled and I hot restart. It worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto index Tab From firebase firestore.
2. Add index

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).